# Using a variable to search for property in window using 'in'

Tags: javascript

I am trying to loop through an array of required names of properties that should be in the Window before the script will continue. However, JavaScript doesn't seem to like it when I use a variable instead of explicit text when using the 'in' keyword.

> TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'ServiceWorker' in
>   window

Am I doing something wrong or is this just the way this works?

```js
const waitForScripts = () => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var required = ["ServiceWorker"];
    var loaded = 0;

    while (loaded <= required.length + 1) {
      if (loaded == required.length) {
        resolve();
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < required.length; i++) {
        var search = required[i];
        if (search in 'window') {
          loaded++;
        }
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: It's strange the error says `window` without quotes. Firefox throws `TypeError: invalid 'in' operand "window"` with quotes.

Comment: It is odd, isn't it? The error Firefox throws seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used the `in` operator on a string, you want to use it on the variable window

```
if (search in window) {
    loaded++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gotta be careful with that `while` loop. If for some reason one of the property names is not on the window object, you will end up with an infinite loop because loaded will not increment.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I just found out for myself. Switched it to an interval which clears itself when they're both equal.